# Did you finish to organize your new apartment?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

I want to know if my friend finish to organized his new apartment.

Is the sentence below sounds good?

> Did you finish to organize your new apartment?

Thank you!

Comment: No it is not.  You probably want, "Did you finish organizing your new apartment?"

Comment: On second reading, the sentence is grammatical, but likely does not mean what you want it to mean.  As written it means, "Is the reason you finished [whatever it was that you were doing]  so that you could go organize your new apartment?"

Comment: Finish, as with other verbs (you have to learn them) is followed by verbs with ING. Finish to  organize is not grammatical in English. You want to know whether your friend finished organizing his apartment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm commenting on the above answer: a better explanation for why it's grammatical is that in spoken American English, we omit some words some times, assuming they are understood. Your sentence means:

Did you finish [some unnamed activity] *in order to* organize your new apartment?

I think you are intending this following meaning instead:

Did you finish organizing your new apartment?

Another way to say it would be:

Did you complete the organization of your new apartment?